# Animate icon don't take his original position on toggle click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a accordion menu which have for each parent menu a icon, and this icon is animated with css transition and transform. I added a class with a if condition to the click event. The problem is that when I click for example on Menu1, the icon animation does very well, but if I click directly on Menu2, the menu2 dropdown appear but icon from the menu1 don't take his original position. 
This problem applies to each icon in each menu/submenu, I thinks that I have a mistake in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Icons effect
    $('#mw_nav .toggle').click(function() { 
        if($(this).hasClass('rotate_close')) 
        {
            $(this).addClass('rotate_open').removeClass('rotate_close');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('rotate_close').removeClass('rotate_open');
        }
    });
    // Toggle Menu Items
    $(function () {
        $("#m_nav > ul ul").hide(); 
        $('#m_nav .toggle').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var $parentli = $(this).closest('li');
            $parentli.siblings('li').find('ul:visible').slideToggle(400);
            $parentli.find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400);
            $(this).remove;
       });
    });
});
```

## [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vhfn0q5a/2/)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues I see with your code.  The first is a recommendation to NOT have $(function() { // your code }) inside of $(document).ready().  $(function() {}) is actually just shorthand for $(document).ready() so you are adding code you do not need.

The second is an issue with your logic.
`$('#mw_nav .toggle')` and `$('#m_nav .toggle')` click listeners are essentially adding a click listener on the same exact element, but both run different logic.  When the `$('#mw_nav .toggle')` click listener is getting called it checks for a class to exist to decide what class it needs to remove and add.  When `$('#m_nav .toggle')` click listener is getting called it calls a slideToggle function on the current nested `<ul>` regardless if another menu is opened or closed and there is no check in place of whether or not the rotate_open/rotate_close classes exist allowing for the classes to get swapped.  There is no relation between the swapping of rotate_open/rotate_close classes and the logic that slideToggles `<ul>` up/down.

**UPDATE**

I have edited your code and made updates that will now work seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/vhfn0q5a/9/

I have added a class of `.top_level` to the top level items in your HTML.  I use this as a way of differentiating the top level `<li>` from the sub menus.  Next, at the end of the click event listener I check to see if the `.toggle` element clicked is a top level element, if so I target all top level elements that are not the current selected and make sure they have the `.rotate_close` class.

[$(function() {}) shorthand reference](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Ok. I removed the function under the $(document).ready(function) and update the code as you mentioned. Now, do you have an example how you could do it? Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/vhfn0q5a/6/

Comment: @colapsnux I have updated my answer to include a working fiddle and explanation of the changes I made.  I believe this should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your first click handler:

```
$('#mw_nav .toggle').click(function() { 

   $(this).toggleClass('rotate_close rotate_open');

   if ($('#mw_nav .toggle').not(this).hasClass('rotate_open')) {

      $('#mw_nav .toggle').not(this).removeClass('rotate_open').addClass('rotate_close');

    }

});
```

I've updated your [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vhfn0q5a/4/) with an working example.

Cheers!

Comment: It works thanks you for your time, but now if I click on the Sub Menu 1, it reset the menu1 icon to his original position and I want to keep his potition after click as long as i'm navigating in the sub menus of the menu1. Should I add another class to the sub menu icons or there is another way to do it ? Thanks you